# Force HTTPS on rewritten url via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

I have a website on `www.domain.com` and here is the root (and only) `.htaccess file`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.(css|js|htc|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm basically doing rewrite on my URL's so everything is going through the `index.php` page.

How can I force **HTTPS (SSL)** on `www.domain.com/login`, `/register` and `/settings`? So when I try to access the `http://www.domain.com/login` I should be immediately redirected to `https://www.domain.com/login`?

I searched SO and I found for folders so if I have folder `/login` it would work, but not for me in this case of **already rewritten** URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Using mod_rewrite you should be able to do something like this

```
    RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} !443
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI} ^/register
    RewriteRule     (.*) https://www.domain.com/register [R]
```

Comment: Hm...no, it's not working :/ I can still access /register through normal HTTP. I put it after the first RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^login$ https://www.domain.com/login     [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^register$ https://www.domain.com/register [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^settings$ https://www.domain.com/settings [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That will do redirect on the level of whole website and I don't want that. I just want on those three pages (login, register, settings). Also it redirects to `www.domain.com/index.php?path=login` and not `www.domain.com/login`

Comment: maybe it doesn't work cause it's *already rewritten* urls, like you mentioned.

Comment: Well, that's why I posted this question (how to make it work) :)

Comment: try to put it as *first rewrite rule* and only then the rest of the rules and let's see if it works then ;)